# Joomla installation extension with progress bar

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

i'm trying to make a progress bar with this function

```
    public function preflight($route, JAdapterInstance $adapter)
    {
        echo '<script>
        console.log("lol");     
        </script>'; 
    }
```

Normally preflight should be execute before all type of action, I tested with a die() it's okay but when you echo or try to execute a js script is not executing before but after.

Do we have a change to make this progress bar ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to echo your script, trying using Joomla's `addScriptDeclaration()` method instead, like so:

```
public function preflight($route, JAdapterInstance $adapter)
{
    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
    $js = '
       console.log("lol");
       // some more code here
    ';

    $doc->addScriptDeclaration($js);
}
```

Note that I haven't used the `<script>` tags, as `addScriptDeclaration()` adds these in automatically for you.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is just wtf. When you mistacke or put die() everything is showing before but echo, print, addscript.... nothing.

Comment: I will do some tests when I get back home later on

Comment: Thanks you for your help, hope we will find a solution :)

Comment: Ok, tried everything no one works. CDATA on xml, scriptfile, installfile, windows.load, unload, ready, jquery, buff, flush, echo, print, return.....

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the same thing with post flight and suspect it might be the same issue.   For me, the problem was Joomla extension installations are done using an AJAX request.  Which means any code executed post and pre flight will be processed server side with any resulting HTML being inserted into the DOM after completion.  So any JavaScript needs to be added to the return HTML and wrapped in the document ready wrapper.  Try adding this and see if something comes up in console.

```
echo "<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    console.log ('lol');
});
</script>";
```

This should confirm whether your issue was tied to AJAX like me or not.

Comment: Hi, I already tried all things like that document ready, load, unload, window ready,... detect if page loaded....